# Eclipse plugin - add mouse listener to an editor everytime its opened

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mouseevent, eclipse-cdt

I am developing an Eclipse plugin and I need to store the click location in X and Y axis coordinates.

So far, I am doing this by using the *org.eclipse.ui.IStartup* interface and using this in the class implementing it:

```java
@Override
public void earlyStartup() {
    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    wb.addWindowListener(generateWindowListener());
}
```

And the in the given method I do this:

```java
private IWindowListener generateWindowListener() 
{
    return new IWindowListener() {

        private MouseListener clickMouseListener = new ClickMouseListener();

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            //Nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            System.out.println("deactivaed");
            IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();
            activePage.getActiveEditor().getAdapter(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.class).addMouseListener(clickMouseListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            //Nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            System.out.println("activated");
            IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();
            activePage.getActiveEditor().getAdapter(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.class).addMouseListener(clickMouseListener);
        }
    };
}
```

So I basically register a listener to the general workbench with the intent to register a new MouseListener - where I save the coordinates - on newly opened editors.

This, however, works only if the entire eclipse window is minimized/maximized, as this listener is bound to the main window. If a new editor is opened, nothing happens (as it probably should work).

I would like to register new MouseListeners everytime a new editor is opened/activated/clicked on - so I can register them to the editor right when a new editor is opened. How can I subscribe/listen to any events related to editors (mostly activated/open new editor) so I can then subscribe a MouseListener to the editor and get current X and Y axis of the mouse-clicks?

Thank for any suggestions.

Comment: You've gone through a number of calls to get to the active editor, have you considered that's you'll also need other listeners in place that actually notify you of editors being opened and closed? Check the `iWorkbenchWindow`, `IWorkbenchPage`, and their super interfaces for places to add listeners.

*So what's this mouse listener for?* A "global" listener like this is awfully intrusive, and you haven't explained what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This mouse listener serves to retrieve the X and Y coordinates of the click. These are stored and used when I do action availability (show/hide action) filtering - I want my action to appear only when a right click happens on a function declaration name. I have managed to do that with the X and Y coordinates, but so far failed to get the correct X and Y coordinates without minimizing/maximizing the entire application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IPartListener` to listen to part events in a workbench window:

```java
IPartService partService = window.getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

This will tell you about all editors (and views) being opened, closed, activiated, ....

In the early startup method the workbench window is not yet available. Use `Display.asyncExec` to delay running your code until the UI initialization is complete:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     IPartService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

     ......
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have one more question as to when to call this method. If I do it in a _IStartup_ interface implemented class, the method _earlyStartup_ returns a null pointer exception for this bit of code: `IPartService partService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();`  on the ActiveWorkbenchWindow part. Could you please suggest, when this listener should be added? My idea was to do this on the startup, hence the _IStartup_ interface used.

Comment: Just testing and windowOpened doesn't work - so use Display.asyncExec - see updated answer.